# Possible to use with statement for condition execution and finalization

Tags: python, with-statement

I have a very common code pattern like this:

```
if not resource.hasInstallTag(tag="mysoftwareservice", version="5"):
    doX()
    doY()   
    frobnicate()   
    do()   
    installMySoftwareService()

    resource.recordInstallTag(tag="mysoftwareservice", version="5")
```

However, its very easy thing to update the version string in one spot, and forget to do it in another, or forget to forget to add the call to recordInstallTag.

I'd like to have something like following pattern:

```
with InstallTag(resource, tag, version):
    doX()
    installTheThingThat(version)
    doY()   
    frobnicate()
```

where:

- if the resource already has tag==tag installed to version==version, then skip the content of the inner statement block (without raising and exception)
- (only) if the inner statement block succeeds without exception, then record that this item with this version was installed to this resource.

For example, something like:

```
class TagAlreadySetException(Exception):
    pass

class InstallTag(object):
    def __init__(self, resource, tag, version):
        self.resource = resource
        self.tag = tag
        self.version = version

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.resource.hasInstallTag(self.tag, self.version):
            # Prevent execution of statement block
            raise TagAlreadySetException()
        return None

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        if type==None:
            self.resource.recordInstallTag(self.tag, self.version)
```

Unfortunately, although raising TagAlreadySetException prevents execution of the statement block, it also continues to throw the exception up the call stack. I'd like to catch TagAlreadySetException and handle it. Can I do this without extra additional machinery around my statement block?

I realize I can do this with try...finally. However, I'm trying to ensure that the tag and item is only written once where the pattern is applied (in order to prevent inconsistencies)

Comment: I think you're trying to do too much with a context manager.  they're made for resource management, not control flow. . . You could do something like:  `with ... as ctx: ctx.check() ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a neat little diddy:

```
import contextlib

def manager_gen(resource, tag, version):
    def check():
        check.called = True
        if resource.hasInstallTag(tag, version):
            raise TagAlreadySetException

    check.called = False

    try:
        yield check
    except TagAlreadySetException:
        pass
    finally:
        if not check.called:
            raise RuntimeError("check wasn't called!")

InstallTag = contextlib.contextmanager(manager_gen)
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
with InstallTag as checker:
    checker()
    raz_the_jazz_and_other_neat_statements()
```

If you forget to run the check, it yells at you at the end of the block (which may or may not be useful . . .)

Comment: Neat. Having to call check is an annoyance, but being able to check for whether it was forgotten helps catch this error.